# Quartz Scheduler in Ktor-Kotlin runs on all the pods of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kotlin, quartz-scheduler, guice, ktor

I am new to Quartz and I am using Quartz 2.3.2 in KTOR application.
This application will run in the cluster using Kubernetes deployment.

My requirement is to run a scheduler in only one instance/pod of this kubernetes framework

I have used below code to run quartz in kubernetes cluster

But below code runs on all the pods of the Kubernetes cluster. How to run on only one instance?

```
object SchedulerMain {
    
        fun schedulerTest(config: DBConfig) {
    
            DBConnectionManager.getInstance().addConnectionProvider(
                "myDs",
                HikariCpPoolingConnectionProvider(
                    "org.postgresql.Driver",
                    config.readerUrl.toString(),
                    config.username,
                    config.password,
                    10,
                    "SELECT * FROM table;"
                )
            )
            val schedFact: DirectSchedulerFactory = DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance()
    try {
        val jobStore = JobStoreTX()
        jobStore.setIsClustered(true)
        jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
        jobStore.tablePrefix = "schema.qrtz_"
        jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
        jobStore.driverDelegateClass = "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate"
        jobStore.dataSource = "myDs"
        val simpleThreadPool = SimpleThreadPool()
        simpleThreadPool.threadCount = 5
        schedFact.createScheduler(
            "TestScheduler", "AUTO", simpleThreadPool, jobStore
        )
        val sched: Scheduler = schedFact.getScheduler("TestScheduler");
        val jobA: JobDetail =
            JobBuilder.newJob(JobA::class.java).withIdentity("jobA", "group2").storeDurably()
                .build()

        val triggerA: Trigger =
            TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("triggerA", "group2").startNow()
                .withPriority(15).withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(40)
                        .repeatForever()
                ).build()

        if (!sched.checkExists(jobA.key)) {
            sched.scheduleJob(jobA, triggerA);
        }
        sched.start()

    } catch (e: SchedulerException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

}

Is AUTO a string?
Pod 1
[image]

Pod 1 and 2 both have same logs
[image]

**Update:**
I truncated all the quartz tables and started kubernetes cluster then it was running on single instance as expected.
Then I stopped the Kubernnetes cluster and started again without truncating tables, the scheduler started on all pods

Answer (score 0):

`Quartz` behaves in clustered mode in a way, that all the work is balanced between nodes to distribute load.
Why are you expecting to have scheduler working only on one node of the cluster?

If you wish for your jobs to be executed non-concurrently, then use `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` on your job class.

Comment: Concurrent seems to refer to one server, not a distributed system.